# ROUND Function - Round up to nearest whole number

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to round up a number to the nearest whole - for example, 4.1 would round to 5, 4 would stay as 4.

5.6 would round to 6, 5.01 would round to 6.00.  any whole numbers would not round but stay the same.

Comment: `Math.ceil` is what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is `Math.ceil()` function

```js
console.log(Math.ceil(4.1))
```